# JOIN on concatenated column performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a view that needs to join on a concatenated column.  For example;

```
dbo.View1 INNER JOIN
dbo.table2 ON dbo.View1.combinedcode = dbo.table2.code
```

Inside the 'View1' there is a column which is comprised like so;

```
dbo.tableA.details + dbo.tableB.code AS combinedcode
```

Performing a join on this column is extremely slow.  However the actual 'View1' runs extremely quickly.  The poor performance comes with the join, and there aren't even many rows in any of the tables or views. Does anyone know why this might be?

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: Do you *have* to perform your join on the concatenated columns or is it conceivable that joining on the original columns individually could yield the same result?

Comment: I have to perform it on the concatenated column unfortunately.  Plus I cannot index an nvarchar column, nor use hints in my view as it gives me "query hints cannot be used in the query plan".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there's no index on `combinedcode`, the `JOIN` will most likely result in a full "table scan" of the view to calculate the code for every row.

If you want to speed things up, try making the view into an [indexed view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933148%28SQL.80%29.aspx) with an index on `combinedcode` to help the join.

Another alternative, depending on your SQL server version, is to (as Parado answers) create a temporary table for the join, although it's usually less performant, at least for single shot queries.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
select *
into #TemTap
from View1
/*where conditions on view1*/
```

after that You could create `index` on `#TemTap.combinedcode` and than

```
dbo.#TemTap as View1 INNER JOIN dbo.table2 ON dbo.View1.combinedcode =
dbo.table2.code
```

It often works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because the optimizer has no information about the concatenated column, so it cannot choose a reasonable join path.  My guess, if you look at the execution plan, is that the join is using a "nested loop" join.  (I'm tempted to add "dreaded" to that.)

You might be able to fix this by putting an index on `table2(code)`.  The optimizer should decide to use this index, getting around the bad join optimization.

You can also use query hints to force the use of a "hash join" or "merge join".  I am finding myself doing this more often for complex queries, where changes to the data might effect the query plan.  (Such hints go in when a query that has been taking 2 minutes for a year decides to take hours, fill the temporary database, and die when it runs out of space.)  You can do this by adding `OPTION (merge join, hash join)` to the end of the query.  You can also explicitly choose the type of join in the `on` clause.

Finally, storing the intermediate results in a temporary table (as proposed by Parado) should give the optimizer enough information to choose the best join algorithm.

Comment: It says "query hints cannot be used in the query plan".  Also I cannot put an index on the column because it is an nvarchar column (a text based code) :-/

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL functions is where condition is not advised. here you are using concatenate in where condition (indirectly but yes). so it is performing concatenation for every row and then comparing it with other table.

Now solution will be try using intermediate table rather then this view to hold the concatinated value.

if not possible try using index view, I know its a hell of task.
I would have preferred creating intermediate table.

see the link for indexed views
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx#Restrictions